# Animate view around circle with arbitrary start point

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I am trying to rotate a bunch of CALayers around a ellipse (carousel style) as follows:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGAffineTransform squash = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 0.8);
CGAffineTransform squashInv = CGAffineTransformInvert(squash);
CGPoint c = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(centre, squashInv);

CGPathAddArc(path, &squash, c.x, c.y, radius, 2.0*M_PI, 0.0, YES);

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAni = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAni.path = path;
pathAni.duration = 14.0;
pathAni.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
CFRelease(path);
```

which works great except each view always starts animating at the 3 o'clock position. Now I'm trying to get my head around starting each view at an arbitrary point along the ellipse and would like some suggestions.

(I've tried CGMoveArcToPoint and also tried to rotate the circle with CGAffineTransformMakeRotate on the path but to no avail)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `timeOffset` property (part of the `CAMediaTiming` protocol)?

> The timing protocol provides the means
>   of starting an animation a certain
>   number of seconds into its duration
>   using two properties: beginTime and
>   timeOffset. The beginTime specifies
>   the number of seconds into the
>   duration the animation should start
>   and is scaled to the timespace of the
>   animation's layer. The timeOffset
>   specifies an additional offset, but is
>   stated in the local active time. Both
>   values are combined to determine the
>   final starting offset.